# Training loop from scratch - manipulate batches

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Is it possible to manipulate the data within each batch from custom training? I need to exclude or include specific samples within each batch. Maybe I would do this by having a dataset with IDs to identify those specific elements.

Would this be possible?

Comment: Does this help ? https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-custom-data-generators-in-keras-de56f013581c

Comment: Yeah this does help! What I want is actually a triplet generator which uses IDs to select postive and negative samples. Do you have any example for that?